# Dell PowerEdge T310 won't POST after memory upgrade

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge, dell

I'm upgrading a PowerEdge T310 to its maximum allowed memory of 32GB. The compatibility information in the manual lists the following:

> Your system supports DDR3 registered DIMMs (RDIMMs) or unbuffered ECC
>   DIMMs (UDIMMs). Single and dual-rank DIMMs can be 1067- or 1333-MHz,
>   and quad-rank DIMMs can be 800- or 1067-MHz. Your system supports
>   single-channel mode and dual-channel mode. The system contains a total
>   of six memory sockets. UDIMM supports single-rank and dual-rank DIMMs.
>   Only RDIMM supports quad-rank DIMMs. The maximum memory that is
>   supported on your system varies according to the types and sizes of
>   memory modules being used:
>
> • Single-rank and dual-rank RDIMMs of sizes
>   2-GB, 4-GB and 8-GB are supported for a total of up to 24 GB.
>
> • Quad-rank RDIMMs are supported for a total of up to 32 GB.
>
> • 1-GB and 2-GB UDIMMs are supported for a total of up to 8 GB.

The system is currently fitted with 4x PC3L-10600 (unbuffered, non-ECC) modules of 4GB each.

If I read this information correctly, I should be able to upgrade this with 4x PC3L-10600R modules of 8GB each, maxing out the available memory and giving me the benefits of ECC.

The memory new I purchased, reading directly from the label on the sticks, is "`8GB 2RX4 PC3L-10600R-9-10-E1`" (Hynix HMT31GR7BFR4A)

After installing the new memory, the system will not POST, and the front LEDs have diagnostic lights 1 and 4 lit. I installed the new sticks into the exact same slots (channels A and B, slots 1 and 2) as the previous memory.

Returning the original memory leads to a normal boot.

I need to know if I've somehow purchased the wrong memory by misreading the information, or if my new memory is faulty somehow (I'd expect a later error, rather than an outright boot failure in this case).

Comment: What does the manual say that lights 1 and 4 signify?

Comment: Just in case you missed it, also note the data width requirements mentioned in the technical guidebook. I've updated my answer to point that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [technical data sheet](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT31GR7BFR4A&rk=20&rc=module) for your memory.

Specifically, the HMT31GR7BFR4A you have is **dual**-rank, not **quad**-rank.

Your system probably does not support dual-ranked 8 GB for 32 GB total (assuming your manual is correct, as it's a bit different from [this technical guidebook](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/poweredge-t310-technical-guidebook-en.pdf)). You'd want HMT31GR7BFR8A, which is quad-ranked 8 GB.

---

Also note from the technical guidebook:

> T310 supports  x8  (data width)  and does  not support x4 and x16 DRAM  on RDIMM

You're attempting to install 2Rx4. HMT31GR7BFR8A is 4Rx8 so I'd expect it to satisfy these requirements.

Of course, other manufacturers (e.g. Samsung) also make RDIMMs in that configuration.

Answer (score 7):

[Diagnostic lights](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/T310-amber-light-how-to-read-the-LED-codes/td-p/4617262) 1 and 4 means system board failure. Either you have the incorrect RAM, A bad ram stick or a bad system board. I looked at the firmware updates and none address an issue with ram.

Comment: That was confusing me too, but I find it very unlikely that the system board has a problem considering it runs completely normally with the memory already in there.

Answer (score 4):

The manual excerpt you provided states `Single-rank and dual-rank RDIMMs of sizes 2-GB, 4-GB and 8-GB are supported for a total of up to 24 GB.`

Your modules are 8GB dual-rank RDIMMS, and exceed the 24GB maximum as per the manual. Try with 3 modules.

Comment: It won't even boot with one or two sticks installed

Answer (score 1):

Dell's documentation is very misleading. In one service manual you'll find "Single-rank and dual-rank RDIMMs of sizes 2-GB, 4-GB and 8-GB are supported for a total of up to 24 GB."
https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t310_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf

And then another manual you'll find "Registered, DDR3 1066 8GB DIMM, Quad Rank"
https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/poweredge-t310-technical-guidebook-en.pdf

According to my test results here is the official supported memory taken from Dell's documentation:

- Unbuffered, DDR3 1066 1GB DIMM, Single Rank
- Unbuffered, DDR3 1333 1GB DIMM, Single Rank
- Unbuffered, DDR3 1066 2GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Unbuffered, DDR3 1333 2GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Unbuffered, DDR3 1066 4GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Unbuffered, DDR3 1333 4GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1066 1GB DIMM, Single Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1333 1GB DIMM, Single Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1066 2GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1333 2GB DIMM, Dual Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1066 4GB DIMM, Quad Rank
- Registered, DDR3 1066 8GB DIMM, Quad Rank

Answer (score 0):

You didn't consider the CPU whether its xeon or other types yet its one of the major factor in PE T310 RAM Upgrade